# No puedo hacer que lo que escribo en el Input se muestre en una imagen

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario muy sencillo, lo que debe hacer este formulario es que al completar un campo, cualquiera sea, el texto escrito en el input se muestre en la tarjeta en tiempo real, intente pasar props y usar el use state para eso, pero no funciona, alguno sabe porque esto no funciona?. Intente buscar informacion en internet pero no me aparece nada util. Por lo tanto cualquier sugerencia me alcanza

'use client'

```
import Image from "next/image";
import fond from "../../../assets/images/fondo.png";
import card from "../../../assets/images/tarjeta-copia.png";
import reverso from "../../../assets/images/tarjeta-rev-copia.png";
import "../../../style/register.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Registrar() {
  const [cardHolder, setCardHolder] = useState("");
  const [cardNumber, setCardNumber] = useState("");
  const [expDateUno, setExpDateUno] = useState("");
  const [expDateDos, setExpDateDos] = useState("");
  const [cvc, setCvc] = useState("");
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="conteiner-pic">
        <Image src={fond} alt="background" className="fondo" />
        <Image src={card} alt={cardHolder} className="tarjeta" />
        <Image src={reverso} alt="tarjeta-reverso" className="tarjeta-reverso" />
      </div>

      <div className="conteiner">
        <form className="formulario">
          <div className="blox">
            <label htmlFor="Cardholder-Name" className="nombre">
              CARDHOLDER NAME
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="Cardholder-Name"
              placeholder="Name card..."
              className="camp"
              value={cardHolder}
              onChange={(e) => setCardHolder(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="blox">
            <label htmlFor="Card-Number" className="nombre">
              CARD NUMBER
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="Card-Number"
              placeholder="Number card..."
              className="camp"
              value={cardNumber}
              onChange={(e)=>{setCardNumber(e.target.value)}}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="conteiner-box">
            <div className="blox">
              <label htmlFor="exp-data" className="nombre">
                EXP. DATA (MM/YY)
              </label>
              <div className="c-campi">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="exp-data"
                  placeholder="mm"
                  className="campi"
                  value={expDateUno}
                  onChange={(e)=>setExpDateUno(e.target.value)}
                />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="exp-data"
                  placeholder="yy"
                  className="campi xc"
                  value={expDateDos}
                  onChange={(e)=>setExpDateDos(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="blox">
              <label htmlFor="cvc" className="nombre">
                CVC
              </label>
              <div className="c-campi">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="cvc"
                  placeholder="CVC"
                  className="campe"
                  value={cvc}
                  onChange={(e)=>setCvc(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button className="boton">Confirm</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Imagen de mi proyecto]

Sin embargo el proyecto deberia estar asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

crei que la logica estaba bien, nose en estoy fallando.

Esto esta hecho en nextJS v13

Comment: A tu codigo le falta toda la parte donde pongas elementos HTML que se muestren encima de las imagenes `tarjeta` y `tarjeta-reverso`, luego de eso, vas a poder conectarlos a cada uno de los states que has creado.

Comment: hola, gracias por contestar. Y como se hace eso en nextjs (o react)

Comment: primero tienes que hacer el HTML, independiente de react

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir jugando con el html y el css en cuanto a las posiciones relativas y absolutas para poder posicionar los valores que tienes en el estado dentro de las imagenes, sería algo asi

```
      <div className="conteiner-pic">
        <Image src={fond} alt="background" className="fondo" />
        {/* // Card front */}
        {/* position relative para el div */}
        <div>
          {/* position absolute para los elementos */}
          {/* mediante las propiedades top, bottom, right y left, vas acomodando cada elemento en el layout */}
          <p>{cardHolder}</p>
          <p>{cardNumber}</p>
          <Image src={card} alt={cardHolder} className="tarjeta" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Image
            src={reverso}
            alt="tarjeta-reverso"
            className="tarjeta-reverso"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/388819)